# w.d format incorrectly handling integers

Tags: sas

I have a column which range from 0 to 1. Most of the values are decimals but some values are exactly 1. When I format the column to 10.4 for example, the 1s get converted to 0.0001 rather than 1.0000! Why is this happening???

```
INFORMAT
probability_of_default 7.4
....
;

FORMAT
probability_of_default 7.4
....
;

INPUT
probability_of_default
;
```

Comment: Can you post your code that would replicate this issue? Given what you've said, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Reeza Just did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you what you did was read the data using an **INFORMAT** of 10.4, instead of displaying the data using a **FORMAT** of 10.4.  If you specify the decimal part of an informat then you are telling SAS that when there is no decimal point in the text that it is reading to assume there is one at `d` characters before the end. So you told SAS to divide the integers by 10**4.  Instead just use an informat without any decimal part, like `10.`, instead of `10.4`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Just 2 quick questions
1) What do you mean "divide the integers by 10**4" ?
2) How would using an informat without any demical part (like 10.) affect decimal values like 0.45?

Comment: @JayNa The informat `.d` portion is intended for very-old-school data storage, where numbers were stored always without decimals, and you had to know where the decimal went.  So "012345.6789" might be the number, but it was written to the file as "0123456789", and then you had to know to use `10.4` informat.  Nowadays, you basically never have to use the `.d` part of the informat - just the `w` part.